# Wordpress wp_logout_url() in IOS gives popup box asking to login

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, safari

I have a link for users on the front end that goes to wp_logout_url() and on desktop it works fine. But when clicked on IOS devices in Safari it shows a popup asking the user to login.

I have searched a long time and cannot find why this is happening.

Thoughts?

Comment: is there any plugin install with yoru WordPress ? Did you try when all plugins & themes disabled ?

Comment: the logout link is actually coming from a plugin. I need it to work in the plugin.

Comment: I never seem to get an answer!